# If magnetic fields are created by moving charges, how do magnets work?

Tags: electromagnetism

This is probably is stupid question but I think it must clear up some misconception I have. Magnets, presumably have magnetic fields. But where are the moving charges? Don't we need a current?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the magnetism in a magnet comes from the magnetic dipole moment of the electrons orbiting its atoms.  If we think of the electron  as a small spinning charged sphere, then it is the spinning chrage that makes the current. Unfortunately this is a not a good model because the surface of the electron (assuming its "classical radius'') will be moving faster than the speed of light. For this reason Pauli originally did not believe in "spin" --- even though he gets most of the credit for the idea.

Comment: For these dipoles, are there also an associated electric field. Is it just so small people don't talk about it?

Comment: The electron does not appear to have an electric dipole moment of its own.  A lot of effort is currently going into to to detect an electric dipole moment of the neutron. This if it exists must  very tiny,  but any non-zero value will  violate both T (time) and P (parity)  invariance.  Quantum Chromodynamics has parameter that has no obvious reason to be zero   but if not zero would give the neutron an electric dipole moment.

Answer (score 1):

> How do magnets work?

The subatomic particles electron, proton and neutron have *magnetic dipole moments*. This magnetic fields are intrinsic properties, means this fields exist under all circumstances. In nonmagnetic materials the sum of all magnetic dipole moments is zero.

In permanent magnets the sum over all this magnetic dipole moments is not zero. To produce strong magnets the material will be milled to powder and than pressed under the influence of a strong external magnetic field. During this production process some electrons are "frozen" with their magnetic fields, all in the same direction along the external magnetic field. Behind a certain temperature the and by the help of the thermic oscillations of the atoms the alignment of the magnetic dipole moments gets lost.

Now your question

> Magnets, presumably have magnetic fields. But where are the moving charges

is answered in a way that moving charges are not involved.

Comment: So take it the other way. How are moving charges involved in the induction of a magnetic field from a current carrying wire bended to a coil? It is conceivable that the magnetic dipole moments of the flowing electrons get aligned during their circular movement through the circular bended wire?

Comment: One day I will send you _how a magnet works_.